# Multiple ObjectMappers for different parts of API

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Currently I have a `@Bean` configuration in my Spring Boot App like that:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

    return mapper;
}
```

Is it possible to have different ObjectMappers for different parts of the API?
I am interested for example to have different property naming strategy for different parts of the API. I want a part of my API (e.g `/api/v1/snake/**`) to work with `SNAKE_CASE` and a part of it (e.g `/api/v1/camel/**`) to work with `LOWER_CAMEL_CASE`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If both parts of the `API` are not dealing with the same domain objects, you'll be able to do it by providing your own implementation of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that overwrite the `canRead` and `canWrite` methods. Here an example using the base package of the object which must be serialized :

**Custom converter :**

```
public class CustomConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private String basePackage;

    public CustomConverter(String basePackage) {
        this.basePackage = basePackage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (contextClass.getName().startsWith(basePackage)) {
            return super.canRead(type, contextClass, mediaType);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (clazz.getName().startsWith(basePackage)) {
            return super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter camelCaseConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new CustomConverter("package.camel");
        converter.setObjectMapper(camelCaseObjectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter snakeCaseConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new CustomConverter("package.snake");
        converter.setObjectMapper(snakeCaseObjectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper camelCaseObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);

        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper snakeCaseObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Bean` of `ObjectMapper` to avoid multi bean errors

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter camelCaseConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new CustomConverter("package.camel");
        converter.setObjectMapper(camelCaseObjectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter snakeCaseConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new CustomConverter("package.snake");
        converter.setObjectMapper(snakeCaseObjectMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    public ObjectMapper camelCaseObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE);

        return mapper;
    }


    public ObjectMapper snakeCaseObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or assign a name to the beans.